# How do i put the label and slider on the same line

Tags: javascript, css

Here is my code, this outputs the slider on one row and then the label on the row below it. When id like them next to each other on the same row.

I've tried using the display value in both the label and the slider, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Any help would be appreciated. Thx in advance.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```css
#slidecontainer {
  width: 70%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<h1>Custom Range Slider</h1>
<p>Drag the slider to display the current value.</p>

<div id="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <label>Value: <span id="demo" display=inline float=left></span></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `.slider` CSS class had `width:100%` set in it, leaving no room for the label. Decreasing that value solves the problem.

Also, your `input` and `label` CSS rules do not do anything helpful here, you should remove them.

Lastly, your `span` that holds the slider's value is invalid:

```
<span id="demo" display=inline float=left>
```

`display` and `float` are CSS properties, not HTML attributes and aren't set this way. Just remove them.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#slidecontainer {
    width: 70%;
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 80%;  /* <-- Problem was here when width is 100% */
    height: 25px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

/* This rule causes the label to vertically align properly */
label {
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-bottom:1em;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}



</style>
<body>

  <h1>Custom Range Slider</h1>
  <p>Drag the slider to display the current value.</p>

  <div id="slidecontainer">
     <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
     <label>Value: <span id="demo"></span></label>
  </div>

  <script>
    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;

    slider.oninput = function() {
      output.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry one more question, how do i center the label to the slider. With the code above the label is aligned to bottom of the slider and actually looks slightly below it.

Comment: @croc_hunter See my updated answer. The `label` element is modified so that it can have a margin added to it. Then a bottom margin is added. Don't forget to mark this as "the" answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple via [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), I have added just 2 rows:

```
#slidecontainer {
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

And here is the snippet:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;

    slider.oninput = function() {
      output.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
```

```css
#slidecontainer {
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input {
    display:inline;
}

label {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Custom Range Slider</h1>
<p>Drag the slider to display the current value.</p>

<div id="slidecontainer">
     <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange" >
     <label>Value: <span id="demo" display=inline float=left></span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. When i try using this in my larger program it doesn't work.  What does the flex properties of css do exactly? I don't think i fully understand why this should work.

Comment: Flex behavior depends on other elements too. But if you're using Flexbox, the best way is to write all markup with flexbox. I recommend you to look through Flexbox docs to get the basic understanding, it's not very hard to use